# Указатели на функции и возвращаемый тип

Tags: c++, указатели

Изучаю C++. остановился на теме "Указатели на функции".

Есть код работающий.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double add(double, double);
double multi(double, double);
double divorce(double, double);

const double* calculate(double, double, double (*pr[3])(double, double));

double  (*pf[3])(double, double) = {&add, &multi, &divorce};

int main()
{
    const double* q = calculate(2.5, 10.4, pf);

    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        cout << q[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

double add(double x, double y)
{
    return x + y;
}

double multi(double x, double y)
{
    return x * y;
}

double divorce(double x, double y)
{
    return x / y;
}

const double* calculate(double x, double y, double (*pr[3])(double, double))
{
    auto* ptr = new double[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        ptr[i] = (*pr[i])(x, y);
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

Если поменять строки

```
double add(double, double);
double multi(double, double);
double divorce(double, double);
```

на

```
const double add(double, double);
const double multi(double, double);
const double divorce(double, double);
```

то тогда выражение 
`double  (*pf[3])(double, double) = {&add, &multi, &divorce};`
нужно поменять на 
`double  (*pf[3])(double, double) = {add, multi, divorce};`

***Почему?***

Да и еще один вопрос.

***Объясните разницу между 
`const double (*pf[3])(double, double)`
и `double (*pf[3])(double, double)`***

Comment: Что значит "нужно поменять"? Кому нужно? Тип функции задается типами параметров и возвращаемым значением. Если что-то изменилось, то тип уже другой и его тоже надо менять.

Comment: Ну, и в вопросе нет ничего с++11 специфичного.

Comment: Менять нужно не на `double  (*pf[3])(double, double) = {add, multi, divorce};`, а на `const double  (*pf[3])(double, double) = {&add, &multi, &divorce};`, хотя взятие адреса вообще-то можно опустить.

Answer (score 1):

Менять необходимо, так как сигнатура функции `double add(double, double);` не соответствует сигнатуре функции `const double add(double, double);`. Различие заключается в наличии const-квалификатора для возвращаемого значения. Причем для простых типов наличие этого const-квалификатора вообще-то не имеет смысла, а для объектов может быть большая разница, например если возвращать просто `std::string x(void)`, то можно написать вот так `x().append("oops");`.

Comment: я понимаю что различие в квалификаторе const но что меняет этот квалификатор?

Comment: Возвращаемое значение не является частью сигнатуры функции.

Comment: @ixSci я думаю, здесь имелся в виду **тип** функции.

Comment: `const double * f()` означает что функция вернет указатель на данные и эти данные нельзя менять, если программист попытается сделать так: `const double * x = f(); *x = 0.1f` или так `duoble * x = f()`, то компилятор сругается. Если убрать `const`, то функция вернет указатель на данные которые можно менять и `double *x = f(); *x=0.1` или `const double *x = f()` сработает.

Comment: @ffk В данном примере функции не возвращают указатели. Они возвращают либо `double`, либо `const double`. И в том, и в другом случае возвращаемое значение изменить нельзя. Но если бы возвращался экземпляр класса, в первом случае возвращаемое значение было бы можно изменить, а во втором - нет, как я уже написал в моем ответе.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас в коде два разных типа, с одной стороны Вы объявляете массив, в который можно помещать объекты такого типа: `double(*)(double, double)`, с другой Вы пытаетесь поместить в этот массив функцию `add` (к примеру), а тип этого выражения будет такой: `const double(*)(double, double)`. Разумеется, что это два разных типа, и Вы не можете просто взять и поместить объект одного типа в массив, который содержит объекты другого типа.

Можно использовать `reinterpret_cast`, если уж очень хочется, но последствия такого решения всегда лежат на программисте.